# Solve the complex equation: $2z = |z + i| + i$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can i solve the equation $2z = |z + i| + i$ in complex number system?

I know that $z = a + bi$ and $\bar{z} = a - bi$.

But then I`m stuck with the absolute value of a trinomial, which squared expression i cant find. Is there something else i can do?

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute value of a trinomial"? In this case, if $z = a + bi$, then $|z + i| = |a + (b+1)i| = \sqrt{a^2 + (b+1)^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $z=a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
$$2a+2bi=\sqrt{a^2+(b+1)^2}+i$$
Now we match the real and imaginary parts
$$2bi=i\implies b=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$2a=\sqrt{a^2+(b+1)^2}\implies 4a^2=a^2+\frac{9}{4}\implies a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
So the unique solution is $z=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Notice that $2z-i$ must be real. If $z =a+bi$, then:
$$2z-i = 2a+(2b-1)i$$
Since this is real, it follows that $b = \frac{1}{2}$. Can you use this to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If $z=a+bi$, with $a,b\in\Bbb R$, then\begin{align}2z=|z+i|+i&\iff2a+2bi=|a+(b+1)i|+i\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}2a=\sqrt{a^2+(b+1)^2}\\2b=1\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}a=\frac{\sqrt3}2\\b=\frac12.\end{array}\right.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As a couple of other ways of working with the equation $ \ 2·z \ = \ |z + i| + i \ \  $ with $ \ z \ = \ a \ + \ bi \ \ : $

•  conjugating the entire equation produces $ \ 2·\overline{z} \ = \ \overline{|z + i|} + \overline{i} \ \rightarrow \ 2·\overline{z} \ = \  |z + i|  - i \ \ , \ $ as the modulus of a complex number is real; since $ \ 2·\mathfrak{Re}(z) \ = \ z + \overline{z} \ \ $ and $ \ 2·\mathfrak{Im}(z) \ = \ z - \overline{z} \ \ , \ $ adding  our "conjugated" equation to or subtracting it from the original one yields

$$ 2·z \ + \ 2·\overline{z} \ \ = \ \ 2·|z + i| \ \ \ , \ \ \ 2·z \ - \ 2·\overline{z} \ \ = \ \ 2·i $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 4·\mathfrak{Re}(z) \ \ = \ \ 2·|z + i| \ \ \ , \ \ \ 4·\mathfrak{Im}(z) \ \ = \ \ 2·i $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 4·b \ \ = \ \  2·i \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b \ \ = \ \ \frac12 \ \ \ , $$
$$ 4·a \ \ = \ \ 2·\left| \ a \ + \ \frac32·i \ \right| \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ \ = \ \ \frac12·\sqrt{ \ a^2 \ + \ \left(\frac32 \right)^2 }  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ a^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac14·a^2 \ + \ \frac14·\frac94 \ \ , \ \ a \ > \ 0^{ \ *} \ \  \Rightarrow \ \ \frac34·a^2 \ \ = \ \frac{9}{16} \ \ , \ \ a \ > \ 0 \ \ $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ a^2 \ \ = \ \frac34 \ \ , \ \ a \ > \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ \ \ .  $$

$ \ ^{*} \ $ we have this condition since $ \ a \ $ is a positive multiple of a modulus

• we will call $ \ \rho \ = \ |z + i| \ > \ 0 \ \ , \ $ making the given equation $ \ 2·z \ = \ \rho + i \ \ ; \ $ so $ \ z \ $ is the scalar multiple of a complex number in the first quadrant and both numbers have the same argument; we may then write $ \frac{b}{a} \  =  \ \frac{1}{\rho} \ \ ; \  $ since $ \ \rho \ $ is real (and non-zero), we have
$$ \ b \ = \ \frac12 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{1 \ / \ 2}{a} \  =  \ \frac{1}{\rho} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ \ = \ \ \frac12·\rho \ \ = \ \ \frac12·\sqrt{ \ a^2 \ + \ ( \ b \ + \ 1 \ )^2 } \ \ = \ \ \frac12·\sqrt{ \ a^2 \ + \ \left( \ \frac12 \ + \ 1 \ \right)^2 } \ \ ,  $$

as before.